# Firebase displayName returns as NULL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am confused as to why when trying to output the display name it returns as NULL yet when I sign up for an account and console.log the displayName it shows my input?

I added a new field:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" style="display:inline;width:auto;" type="text" id="displayName" name="displayName" placeholder="displayName"/>
```

Inside of the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {` function I did a console.log against `displayName` and it output when the field where submitted and created the user in the DB, but when outputting the `displayName` is returns as `NULL`

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').disabled = true;
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          var displayName = user.displayName;
```

Im just doing a simple text output on the users details like so:

```
document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify(user, null, '  ');
```

Comment: Are you setting the displayName via firebase.auth().updateProfile({displayName: 'John Doe'}); If there is no display name set then you will always get a null display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you are executing

`document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify(user, null, '  ');`

before `user` is populated.

If so, try executing the above code inside the `if (user) {}` block.

Comment: That's where it currently is

Comment: Can you verify that the block is being executed?  (i.e. Add a console log in `if (user) {...}`

Comment: It does console log out yes, I can access the uid like user["uid"] and it gives me the logged in users uid - but if I try go after the displayName it comes back as NULL

Comment: Where are you trying to access the value of `displayName`? Are you trying to access `displayName` outside of that `if (user) {...}` block?

Comment: I want to be able to store it from an input field and i assumed because its available to me i thought i could use it?

Comment: Also, can you ensure that the `user` has a `displayName` set?  Please explicitly update the `user`'s profile:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136107/discussion-between-phpdude-and-raphael-rafatpanah).